# ALAssetsLibrary, ALAsset and Memory Warning for 3 Images Display On Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management, alassetslibrary

My app retrieves the last 100 photos with `ALAssetsLibrary` and `ALAsset`. I apply **lazy load** technique to avoid loading more than 3 images on screen. This is the flow:

1. loop though assets with `ALAssetsLibrary` to get last 100
2. store each `ALAsset` in `NSMutableArray`:

   `[self.pageImages addObject:asset];`
3. load maximum 3 images on screen: one image to view now, one image for next and one for previous pages
4. scrolling to the next image removes previous and adds one new image to the view

BUT I still receive **memory warning**, and especially if swiping/scrolling is too fast.

What additional suggestions or approaches to use dealing with `ALAsset`? Here is the code:

```
    ALAsset * asset = [self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page];
    NSLog(@"asset %@",asset);
    ALAssetRepresentation *arep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    
    // Retrieve the image orientation from the ALAsset
    UIImageOrientation orientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
    NSNumber* orientationValue = [asset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"];
    if (orientationValue != nil) {
        orientation = [orientationValue intValue];
    }
    
    CGFloat scale  = 1;
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[arep fullResolutionImage]
                                         scale:scale orientation:orientation];
```